# Are there non-holonomic constraints that cannot be removed, other than conservation of energy?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws

I'm learning about Lagrangian mechanics at the moment.  The idea that $ L(\mathbf{q}(t),\mathbf{\dot{q}}(t), t) = 0$ fascinates me.

It strikes me as this could be viewed as a 1st order non-holonomic constraint, simply providing a constraint that energy is conserved.  I also know that many of the other conservation laws, such as conservation of momentum, can be derived from symmetries in systems which have this particular constraint (thanks to Nother's theorem).

My question: are there believed to be fundamental non-holonomic constraints which cannot be removed by a wise choice of generalized coordinates or more complete modeling?  All of the examples I can find suggest that the non-holonomic constraints are a side effect of using inconvenient coordinate systems or incomplete mechanics (such as modeling the complex interaction of two rough surfaces as "friction" generating "heat")

Comment: FWIW, a [ball rolling without slipping on a plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonholonomic_system#Rolling_sphere) is an example of a semi-holonomic constraint that is not holonomic. Although friction forces are present at the point of contact, in the ideal model, friction does no work.

Comment: @Qmechanic That is definitely useful for the intuition I am trying to acquire, so thank you, but it's not *quite* where I was looking to go.  Said friction, at a more fundamental level, would be built up of electrostatic forces between the ball and the plane, where the molecules in the plane have holonomic constraints preventing them from moving. (or we can continue the process to make the system larger until it encompasses everything)

Comment: @CortAmmon nicht holonomic constraint mean that the velocity coordinates are  constraint $\psi(\vec{q},\vec{\dot{q}})=0$
is not constraint of the Lagrangian?